# using two separate keys in BoltDB

Tags: go, boltdb

I have a `User` struct with `ID` and `LoginName` fields and I want this struct to be accessible by either of these fields with single call to the DB. I know BoltDB is not supposed to handle arbitrary field indexing etc. (unlike SQL) but this case is a little different as I happen to know in advance the additional field to b used as index.

So is there some kind of secondary key or multiple key indexing? or maybe some strategy that I fail to see? If not then I'll just implement it with two calls, I just prefer a "cleaner" solution...

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like the perfect use-case for SQLite; BoltDB is great, but you will have to jump through a few (error prone) hoops to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not there.  BoltDB is a lot like Go.  Clean and simple.  And building a layer on top is easy.  BoltDB even allows update transactions to be trivially implemented so two more more buckets can be updated, or not, atomically.  So creating an update transaction that keeps two or more buckets in sync is easy.  But it sounds like you know that and just wanted to check that you aren't missing something.

Comment: yep. this is what I did

Answer (score 2):

There is no secondary key indexing in BoltDB, but you can implement it.

You can store ID to LoginName mapping in another bucket, and it will be technically the "secondary key" for your struct. That is, first obtain the primary key value from the secondary key, and then the User struct.

If most of your calls are on LoginName key, use LoginName to ID mapping and store User struct under LoginName key and vice versa.

Be careful: you have to maintain consistency by your own, remember it.